# Word meaning 'enhance' or 'improve'

Tags: meaning

I heard a word meaning *enhance* and *improve* that sounded like *horn*, e.g. 'horn technical skills'. What is the spelling of this word?

I unsuccessfully tried to [Google](https://www.google.com.np/search?q=horn%20technical%20skill&rlz=1C1CHMO_enNP542NP542&oq=horn%20technic&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i57j69i60l2.2002j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8) it.

Answer (score 4):

The word is most likely *hone*.

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/hone

See definition 5:

*hone: 5. to make more acute or effective; improve; perfect:
to hone one's skills.*

Comment: What happens when that dictionary link changes and breaks? Please quote the relevant part of the reference (with the link and citation -- we just need the text as well).

Comment: @AndrewLeach Done.

Answer (score 1):

I think the word you heard was "hone". To hone one's skills is to improve them.
From Merriam-Webster.com:

Hone (verb)-
1 :  to sharpen or smooth with a whetstone

2:  to make more acute, intense, or effective :  whet

Comment: I don't wish to damp your enthusiasm, but this answer has already been given.  :)

Comment: Well, it was given while I was writing it. I'm pretty sure it's fine to have more than one answer.