# Is there a non-compound synonym for 'ever-improving'?

Tags: synonyms, epithet-requests

Trying to find out a simpler way to refer to someone who is actively looking to grow and excel at what she is doing.

Comment: Is that what you think "ever-improving" means?

Comment: 'ambitious' maybe.  Can you provide a sample sentence with a gap where the word would go?

Comment: Honing your skilles http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/226261/word-meaning-enhance-or-improve

Comment: "Perfectionist" ?

Answer (score 2):

It’s not all the way there, but for me “**progressing**” alone (“**advancing**,” too for that matter) contains more of the notion of “ever” (or at least continuity toward the next level) than “improving” alone does.

Although not quite to the point of rendering “ever-progressing” (or “ever-advancing”) redundant, it is used (without “ever”) [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=iM4aAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA393&lpg=PA393&dq=progressing+%22ever-improving%22&source=bl&ots=yVWGJJ3Cdg&sig=9LzbpoShdg5CQfO0Jto1wkrZ0uU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDkQ6AEwBWoVChMIkNPAt7PFyAIVQhk-Ch1zEAcY#v=onepage&q=progressing%20%22ever-improving%22&f=false)  together with “ever-improving” (although one could argue that the author intended the “ever” to carry-over to “progressing”). (example of this usage from ‘The Brahmavâdin, Volume 8’/Google Books)

**Progress[ing]**-verb: “[B2 to improve or develop in skills, knowledge, etc. / C2 to continue gradually](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/progress)

**Advanc[e/ing]**-verb: “[(MOVE FORWARD) … to go or move something forward, or to develop or improve something](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/advance)

(both from Cambridge Dictionaries Online)